# Python Function Codecademy

Tags: python

I'm trying to cube the number in this function, but Codecademy says it isn't returning the right result.  Could anyone help?

```
def cube(number):
    return number**number
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3==0: 
        return cube(number)
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: Number ** number would raise number to the power of number (not square or cube) .

Comment: Why did you think it *was* returning the right result? Didn't you test it yourself?

Comment: @elethan yeah, had the OP tested with any value other than `0`, `1` or `3` (or, possibly, at all) they would have probably spotted the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not a cube. Cube is: number ** 3

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in one liner of this function check this out:

```
def by_three(number):
    return number ** 3 if number % 3 == 0 else False
```

If you are interested in how this is done check [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) in python

Answer (score 1):

Given your `cube` function, you are doing

```
n^n
```

for example, given n = 4, what you are really doing is 4*4*4*4

And it work only on 3 or it's multiple, given the line

```
if number % 3==0:
```